# Anyone knows how to swich between displayed files in visual studio code?

Tags: file, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

So i'm coding with two classes in visual studio and i have both of them displayed at the same time.

Is any keyboard shortcut to switch between them without using the mouse?

Is pretty anoying to use the mouse everytime.

Comment: Open your Gear/Keyboard Shortcuts and do a search for `open editor` - you will see many available shortcuts and commands for switching editors.

Comment: "*both of them displayed at the same time*" You mean you have [split/side-by-side editor view](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_side-by-side-editing)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a hotkey to switch between split window panes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36328029/is-there-a-hotkey-to-switch-between-split-window-panes)

Answer (score 1):

`CTRL`+ `pageup` should do what you need

Answer (score 1):

You can split the editor and view both classes side by side and switch between with Ctrl+1 and Ctrl+2 up to Ctrl+9

Ctrl+0 will bring you to the View Bar

Answer (score 0):

and to close the current tab :

**CTRL + W**