# Switch multiple panes without repeat keystrokes in VSCodeVim

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

Say I have three panes arranged like the following.

```
-------------------
|     |     |     |
|  A  |  B  |  C  |
|     |     |     |
-------------------
```

If I was in pane `A`, *normally*, I would navigate to pane `C` using <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>. Is there a built in way to traverse from pane `A` to pane `C` without repeating the key strokes? For example, something similar to <kbd>2</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>.

Note: I am using Vim emulation on VSCode where it can be more difficult to add this customizability myself.

Comment: Yes, `2 ctrl-w l` works. Vim's help is very bad, to read about this, use `:h CTRL-W_<Right>`

Comment: I guess I should've tried in native Vim. It doesn't seem to be supported using Vim emulation on VS. I'll edit the question to be more specific to my environment.

Comment: If you you've learned enough Vim to be an efficient Vim user, meaning if you've learned all the nasty bells and whistles you need to glue together in Vim to try to be productive, then you'll find there's no such thing as a good "vim mode" in other editors, because they only implement the basics of Vim, not the things you actually need.

Answer (score 0):

As Andy Ray mentioned, <kbd>2</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> does indeed work on native Vim. However, Vim emulation on VSCode does not support this.

According to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36328029/is-there-a-hotkey-to-switch-between-split-window-panes#:%7E:text=For%20Mac%20users%20and%20the%20latest%20VS%20Code,pane%20number%202%20Cycling%20between%20all%20open%20files%3A), you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> which does work when using Vim emulation, but is not ideal when you have horizontally split panes and will not work in native Vim.

Answer (score 0):

In Vim, you can simply go from A to C with `<C-w>W`. In your Vim emulator, well… who knows how well it emulates the original?